# MS Office365 Metadata URI Query

Tags: office365, office365api

I am working on MS Office365 version 2.0 having metadata URI:
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata

This document includes all the EntityType supported by Office365 REST API.

In addition to this, there are few more EntityType like Conversation,ConversationThread,Post,Group etc.
But when I try to access these EntityType with my office365 credentials using URI:
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/Conversations

I am getting following error:
"Resource not found for the segment 'Conversations'".

Additionally I found that the above mentioned EntityType are supported by Graph API.

So I had few queries regarding the same:

- Is the metadata URI same for MS Office 365 API and Graph API
- Is there any way to differentiate between the EntityType of Office 365 and Graph.

Let me know for any details.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This objects were available through the **Office 365 unified API** previously. And now it is renamed to **Microsoft Graph**.

We can list the conversations for the specific group like the request below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<id>/conversations
```

More detail about Microsoft Graph you can refer [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list_conversations).

Comment: Is there any way to differentiate the EntityType of MS Office365 from Graph?

I am working on MS Offcie365 and i need to get the Entity Type that are specific to Office.

Also, I would like to know that are Graph API and Offcie365 API refering to same metadata document?